# Showdialog disappears when using alt + tab

Tags: vb.net, showdialog

I have a MDI container and also I use my own custom class MsgBox called ShowMsg which I use mostly on the child forms, so far it worked fine until I realized that the Showmsg (which is a ShowDialog) did not stick to the parent form (MDIContainer).

In a child form, I use a thread to run a process and show a progress bar, if the user switch to another program using alt+tab while the process is working and finishes, when user returns to my app using Alt+Tab, the ShowMsg is not there, it disappears and there's nothing I can do to bring it back, so my app becomes useless.

This only happens when calling it from a different thread than the Form itself, I am pulling my hair off with this, why disappears????

This is part of the code:

```
Public Function ShowMsg(ByVal Text As String, ByVal Icon As ShowMsgImage, ByVal Title As String) As DialogResult
    Dim SMF As New ShowMsgForm

    'Set the title bar
    SMF.Text = Title

    'Select an image and sound based on the Icon parameter
    Select Case Icon
        Case ShowMsgImage.Alert
            SMF.MessagePictureBox.Image = My.Resources.ico_showmsg_Warning
            SMF.Sound = Media.SystemSounds.Asterisk
        Case ShowMsgImage.Confirm
            SMF.MessagePictureBox.Image = My.Resources.ico_showmsg_Confirm
            SMF.Sound = Media.SystemSounds.Question
        Case ShowMsgImage.Critical
            SMF.MessagePictureBox.Image = My.Resources.ico_showmsg_NotAllowed
            SMF.Sound = Media.SystemSounds.Hand
        Case ShowMsgImage.Info
            SMF.MessagePictureBox.Image = My.Resources.ico_showmsg_Info
            SMF.Sound = Media.SystemSounds.Asterisk
        Case ShowMsgImage.Security
            SMF.MessagePictureBox.Image = My.Resources.ico_showmsg_Lock
            SMF.Sound = Media.SystemSounds.Beep
        Case ShowMsgImage.UnderConstruction
            SMF.MessagePictureBox.Image = My.Resources.ico_showmsg_NotAllowed
            SMF.Sound = Media.SystemSounds.Asterisk
        Case ShowMsgImage.Ok
            SMF.MessagePictureBox.Image = My.Resources.ico_showmsg_ok
            SMF.Sound = Media.SystemSounds.Asterisk
    End Select

    'Set other properties
    SMF.TextLabel.Text = Text
    SMF.QuestionTextLabel.Text = ""
    SMF.Button1.Visible = True
    SMF.Button1.Text = "OK"
    SMF.Button1.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK
    SMF.Button2.Visible = False
    SMF.Button3.Visible = False

    'Resize the form
    SMF.SizeForm()

    'Set its starting position
    SMF.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen

    'Display the form modally and return its DialogResult
    Try
        Return SMF.ShowDialog()
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try


End Function
```

Sample on the child:

```
Private Sub btnGo_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnGo.Click
    Dim backgroundThread As New Thread(AddressOf Processdata)
    backgroundThread.Start()

End Sub

Sub ShowMsgDelegate(msg As String)
    ShowMsg(msg, ShowMsgImage.Ok, "")
End Sub

Delegate Sub MyDelegate(ByVal msg As String)

Private Sub Processdata()
    'Do stuff and when finished...
    Me.Invoke(New MyDelegate(AddressOf ShowMsgDelegate), New Object() {"Done"})
End Sub
```

Comment: The first thing I would do is check the ID of the current thread at various places to check that the code is executing on the UI thread or a secondary thread as expected.  At a glance, your code looks OK but it's not working as expected so there's obviously something not obvious going on, so you should check the things that seem to obviously be the case rather than assuming that they are.

Answer (score 0):

After several days and tests, I think I found the answer.

I added:

- TopLevel = True when showing
- Paramenter ParentForm

  ```
          SMF.TopLevel = True
          Return SMF.ShowDialog(**frm**)
  ```

Where frm is the form that calls ShowMsg

Comment: LOL, I just finished test and was about to suggest this.  The problem is that `SMF` falls behind the main form in the z-order.  That said, you should have see the dialog form when Alt-Tabbing and been able to select it, or select it from the task bar (on Win 10 at least).